# Material-Table - How to change Detail panel Icon rotation when the row is expanded?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I have changed the positioning of the detail panel icon (mui ChevronLeft) to the right of the table using the following prop `options={{detailPanelColumnAlignment: "right"}}`.

**TableIcons :**

```
    DetailPanel: forwardRef((props, ref) => (
      <ChevronLeft
        {...props}
        className="accordion_button ml-0"
        sx={{ color: "#ff7b00" }}
        ref={ref}
      />
    )),
etc ...
```

**Table prop to change icon position :**

```
options={{
   detailPanelColumnAlignment: "right", etc...
}}
```

However, whenever the detail panel is open, it rotates towards to top rather than the bottom. When I inspect I find that the IconButton that wraps the ChevronLeft component is being styled with `transform: rotate(90deg);`. If I could somehow override this javascript I believe it would solve my problem but i don't know how I could go about doing that.

Does the MT package provide a way to customize the rotation of the detail panel icon ? If not is there a way I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Considering Icon is wrapped by IconButton

```
<ChevronLeft
        {...props}
        className="accordion_button ml-0"
        sx={[
         detailPanelColumnAlignment === 'right' && {  // if its true, below css gets applied
           [`&.${iconButtonClasses.root}`]: {
              transform: rotate(180deg); // check with the degree value
           }
         }
        ]}
        ref={ref}
      />
```

Comment: I don't see how I could make this work as the detailPanelColumnAlignment variable is undefined.

Comment: if you dont rely on `detailPanelColumnAlignment`, then remove `detailPanelColumnAlignment === 'right' && `

Comment: detailPanelColumnAlignment is a material-table property that can be set inside of options prop, I don't think I have access to it at the detail panel icon level. If I did it would certainly solve the issue, but It's not the case unfortunately.